# Bootstrap "type alignment" in react-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am migrating a web app built with Bootstrap to React and react-bootstrap, both of which are awesome. The one thing I don't see in react-bootstrap is how to smoothly integrate Bootstrap's [type alignment classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#type-alignment) such as `text-center`. My app is wrapped in

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
```

I see two ways around this, but I am wondering if there is a recommended way around this that is not such a hack.

a. Replace my `<Grid>` JSX tag with `<Grid bsClass="text-center container">`. This seems to work fine, but I see in the [`react-bootstrap` docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#grid-props-grid) that "Generally one should only change bsClass to provide new, non-Bootstrap, CSS styles for a component." I can even add the `fluid` prop to `Grid` and it changes `container` to `container-fluid` without breaking.

b. Wrap everything in `<div className="text-center">`. One of the things I love about `react-bootstrap` is the clean code without a zillion extra `<div>`s, so this is inelegant.

As I say, just wondering whether there is an existing way to do this. It would be great to have some comment on this in the `react-bootstrap` docs, since it is a section of the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#type-alignment) that doesn't seem to be mentioned at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would add the class manually with `<Grid className="text-center" >`, especially considering you mentioned this is a single element wrapping your app rather than an element that will be reused in different situations.